# Create list of ordered pairs from csv data in python

Tags: python, list, csv

Please reference data here: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/brooksandrew/f989e10af17fb4c85b11409fea47895b/raw/a3a8da0fa5b094f1ca9d82e1642b384889ae16e8/nodelist_sleeping_giant.csv

The last two columns of the data represent [X,Y] coordinate pairs. I want to take this data and organize it into a list of paired lists in python so that it looks like:

```
coords = [[1486,732],[716,1357],...,[X_ii, Y_ii]]
```

So far I have tried this:

```
  nodelist = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/brooksandrew/f989e10af17fb4c85b11409fea47895b/raw/a3a8da0fa5b094f1ca9d82e1642b384889ae16e8/nodelist_sleeping_giant.csv')
  coord_array = pd.DataFrame(nodelist.iloc[:,1:].iterrows())
  coords = [[tuple(x)] for x in coord_array.values][0]
```

But this outputs:

```
[[[(0, X    1486
    Y     732
    Name: 0, dtype: int64)], [(1, X     716
    Y    1357
    Name: 1, dtype: int64)], [(2, X    3164
    Y    1111
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve dtypes while iterating over the rows, it is better to use `itertuples()` which returns `namedtuples` of the values and which is generally faster than `iterrows()`. [Read more here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

`[[e.X, e.Y] for e in nodelist.itertuples()]`

Comment: This actually creates tuples instead of lists. I can also recreate this by doing: `x = nodelist['X']; y = nodelist['Y']; coords = list(zip(x, y))`

Comment: I have changed my answer, now it makes list of lists.

Comment: Please add a bit of explanation so it's not only code.